# I can't save .txt file with QFileDialog, C++ QT

Tags: c++, qt, qfile, qfiledialog, qtextstream

This is my code:

```
void MainWindow::save(){
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Text File"), path, tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
    if (fileName != "")
    {
       QFileInfo info(fileName);
       path = info.absoluteDir().absolutePath();
       QFile file(path);
       if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){
           QString text = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
           QTextStream out(&file);
           out << text ;
           file.close();
       }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't create any .txt file after click a pushButton:

```
connect(ui->saveButton, SIGNAL(clicked(bool)), this, SLOT(save()));
```

Log:

```
QIODevice::write (QFile, "C:\Users\kfg\Desktop"): device not open
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: `if(!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly)){` are you sure you want to write to the file when `open` fails?

Comment: Go to `C:\Users\` and check that your current user account and the Administrators group have full access to **kfg**'s profile folder. See the article: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/unable-to-save-a-file-to-my-local-user-folder/3d3bfcc1-48c4-4c24-9e35-0f0d77b9befb

Comment: More explicit than @SimonKraemer's comment (so that I can vote to close this as a typo that cannot be reproduced anymore): your error checking is reversed. As written you are trying to write only when the open fails, and if the open succeeds you do not try to write.

Comment: @VladimirBershov there is no need for him to do that. Read his code with close attention to his error checking inversion.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You make 2 mistakes.

The first is here in the line `path = info.absoluteDir().absolutePath();`
This will give you the path of the directory, not the file. You should use `path = info.absoluteFilePath();`. See [`QFileInfo::absoluteFilePath()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qfileinfo.html#absoluteFilePath).

The next is that you write to the "file" when `open` returns `false` (fails).

I think for your code to be correct you should use something like this:

```
void MainWindow::save() 
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Text File"), path, tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
    if (fileName != "")
    {
        QFile file(QFileInfo(fileName).absoluteFilePath());
        if (file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            QString text = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
            QTextStream out(&file);
            out << text;
            file.close();
        }
        else
        {
            //TODO: Error message
        }
    }
}
```

You might also want to check whether the file already exists and ask the user if it is ok to overwrite it...

```
void MainWindow::save() 
{
    QString fileName = QFileDialog::getSaveFileName(this, tr("Save Text File"), path, tr("Text Files (*.txt)"));
    if (fileName != "")
    {
        QFile file(QFileInfo(fileName).absoluteFilePath());

        if (file.exists())
        {
            QMessageBox::StandardButton chosenButton 
                = QMessageBox::warning(this, tr("File exists"), tr("The file already exists. Do you want to overwrite it?"), 
                    QMessageBox::Ok | QMessageBox::Cancel, 
                    QMessageBox::Cancel);
            if (chosenButton != QMessageBox::Ok)
            {
                return; //Save was cancelled
            }
        }
        if (!file.open(QIODevice::WriteOnly))
        {
            QMessageBox::critical(this, tr("Error"), tr("Failed to save file"));
            return; //Aborted
        }
        //All ok - save data
        QString text = ui->plainTextEdit->toPlainText();
        QTextStream out(&file);
        out << text;
        file.close();
    }
}
```

You should also check whether writing into the file actually succeeded.